# Отсутствие перевода текста про рассылку на странице регистрации

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, регистрация

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. > Opt-in to receive occasional product updates, user research invitations, company announcements, and digests.
2. При нажатии на вопросик:

   > We know you hate spam, and we do too. That’s why we make it easy for you to update your email preferences or unsubscribe at anytime.
   >   We never share your email address with third parties for marketing purposes.